# SVG hover not working in IE9 or Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, svg

I have a basic `SVG` that displays the title when you hover over the object. It works fine in  FF 38 but not at all in IE9 or Chrome.

Are there specific requirements for Chrome and IE that I'm missing?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5doy3wtq/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SVG tooltips are implemented as child title elements and not as title attributes as they are in html. So you need to create something that looks like this...

```
<path d="whatever">
    <title>Yellow 999</title>
</path>
```

What you're seeing is a [bug in Firefox that I fixed recently](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1235066). Firefox 46 onwards will work the same as Chrome and IE and not show a title attribute as a tooltip.